# How does java compare numbers of different types?

Tags: java, floating-point

In short: how does Java compare numbers of different types? Specifically: int, long, float, and double. For the purpose of this question, comparing means `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=`; I understand the difficulties and problems of using `==` and `!=` with floating point numbers.

If two numbers are of the same type (both ints, both doubles, or etc.), comparing them is easy; there are probably direct CPU instructions to do it, and even if not (ancient CPUs?) there are standards for doing so.

Comparing certain pairs of types *seems* straightforward; if `a` is an `int` and `b` is a `long`, then we can upcast `a` to a `long` in a lossless way and compare them directly (similarly if `a` and `b` are reversed, or if we exchange `int/long` for `float/double`). I don't know if java actually does it this way, though.

But more controversial is comparing ints/longs with floats/doubles.  If I have (say) a long of an integer value that a float can't represent exactly, then how it rounds to a float will affect how it compares to that float. However, there *is* a right answer, even if it's not clear what it is by casting.

For example if (these are not real examples but real examples exist) `a=10001` but float can only encode `10000f` and `10002f` but nothing in between, then there is a standard rounding procedure where `(float) a` is exactly one of those two things. But what we should have is that `10000f < a` and `a < 10002f`, which can't be achieved by rounding and then comparing.

So does Java do this in a smarter way? Or does it round and then make some mistakes?

Comment: it rounds and makes some mistakes

Comment: Look up "binary numeric promotion" in the JLS. The rules are precise and explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all answered in the Java Language Specification.  The conversions are listed in [section 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B.2)

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>     to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>     to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

And the widening primitive conversion details specify the following ([section 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)).

> A widening primitive conversion from int to float, or from long to float, or from long to double, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value. In this case, the resulting floating-point value will be a correctly rounded version of the integer value, using IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode

which is further clarified thus ([section 4.2.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4)).

> The Java programming language requires that floating-point arithmetic behave as if every floating-point operator rounded its floating-point result to the result precision. Inexact results must be rounded to the representable value nearest to the infinitely precise result; if the two nearest representable values are equally near, the one with its least significant bit zero is chosen. This is the IEEE 754 standard's default rounding mode known as round to nearest.

So, yes, comparing a `long` to a `float` or a `double` can return an incorrect result, because there are `long` values that can't be represented by `float` or `double`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. It's disappointing that it can't be done accurately but I can see why this is part of the language spec. In practice I suppose it comes up very rarely, and is just another case of not wanting ints and floats to interact.

Comment: You can always convert both operands to `BigDecimal` and use `compareTo` if you need to compare `long` with `float` accurately.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.BigInteger` and `java.lang.BigDecimal` provide functionality to extend mathematical processing to an arbitrary precision... Limited, of course, by the constraints of the computer's resources (CPU and memory mostly)